# Unable to Run GraalVM image on Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, graalvm

I am unable to run GraalVM image on Docker,

I am getting error:

```
exec ./legacy-server: exec format error
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY target/legacy-server legacy-server
ENTRYPOINT ["./legacy-server"]
```

when I run locally via `./target/legacy-server` it works perfectly fine.

Here is the PR with the changes: https://github.com/quiz-roulette/legacy-service/pull/1

Comment: "The error Exec format error means that the binary being executed is made for a different architecture than the environment currently booted.". You generally can't just copy an executable from the host into an image. Architectures have to match and any libraries it depends on have to be present.

Comment: Well that makes sense. Let me find out how can i build the image in the same place.